# add rows automatically row html data grid with drop down menu

Tags: javascript, html, button

I would like to ask if you can help me fix my code. I built an HTML grid and have a button that should automatically add a new row. The function associated with the button doesn't work.

Here's the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>  
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
            <tr>
                <th>Advertiser</th>
                <th>Formato</th>
                <th>Tipo</th>
                <th>Autoplay</th>
                <th>Audio</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row1">
                <td id="advertiser_row1">
                    <select name="client">
                        <option value="Mcvities">Mcvities</option>
                        <option value="Enel">Enel</option>
                        <option value="Brita">Brita</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="formato_row1">
                    <select name="formato">
                        <option value="intro shaa">intro shaa</option>
                        <option value="intro xaxis">intro xaxis</option>
                        <option value="carousel">carousel</option>
                        <option value="mid-strip">mid-strip</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="tipo_row1">
                    <select name="tipi">
                        <option value="video">video</option>
                        <option value="immagine">immagine</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="audio_row1">
                    <select name="audio">
                        <option value="video">yes</option>
                        <option value="immagine">no</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td id="tipo_row1">
                    <select name="autoplay">
                        <option value="video">yes</option>
                        <option value="immagine">no</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_cl"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_fo"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_ti"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_au"></td>
                <td><input type="text" id="new_at"></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here my js:

```
function add_row()
{
 var new_ad=document.getElementById("new_cl").value;
 var new_im=document.getElementById("new_fo").value;
 var new_cp=document.getElementById("new_ti").value;
 var new_st=document.getElementById("new_au").value;
 var new_en=document.getElementById("new_at").value;

 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='advertiser_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_cl+"</td><td id='formato_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_fo+"</td><td id='tipo_row"+table_len+"'>"+ti_cp+"</td><td id='audio_row"+table_len+"'>"+au_cl+"</td><td id='autoplay_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_at+"</td>;

 document.getElementById("new_cl").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_fo").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_ti").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_au").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_at").value="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change: `<table id="myTable">`

```
function add_row()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
    cell3.innerHTML = "NEW CELL3";
    cell4.innerHTML = "NEW CELL4";
}
```